printing out a sequence using list comprehension instead of for loop
Using python,I want to generate a sequence [0,2,6,12,20,30,42,56,72,90];
The logic that I've figured out is like this
i,j =0,0
for i in range(1,10):
j+= 2*i
print(j)

Instead of for loop, I need to generate the same using list comprehension
and I've tried my best to do so, but in the end no result.
I've tried using this
j =[0]
j = [j[i-1] + 2*i for i in range(1,10)]

and I ended up getting list out of index error, rightfully so.
I've no clue how to do this; Hence I'm here.
Can anyone help me out?
P.S. I don't want to rely on any generative AI tools for this problem.

What makes you think this can be done w/ a list comprehension?

Why do you "need" to use a list comprehension?

What exactly do you want printed?

Don't use a list comprehension to print. Use a list comprehension to build a list. If you then want to print that list, that's trivial and not worth asking, you'd then better just ask about building the list without printing.

Yes you're certainly right about it, need to build a list using list comprehension, rather than to print it out using a list comprehension.

List comprehensions can't access their previous result, so a list comprehension isn't ideal here without some hacks. What is ideal is itertools.accumulate:
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate(range(10), lambda j, i: j + 2 * i))
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]


Thank you mate, was trying to use lambda expression in it without itertools, but the plan backfired, since the idea of using itertools didn't crossed my mind. I appreciate your time and effort. I'll improve my skills. If you anything that can help me to do so, I'd be glad to look up.

You can use Walrus operator
python >=3.8
Walrus
j=0
[j:= j + 2 * i for i in range(1,10)]

Output
#[2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]


This is very strange. I came up with precisely this answer (before I saw this obviously) and it was downvoted. Once again I say this... If people are going to downvote they should be obliged to provide a justification. I've upvoted this so I'm interested to follow it and see if the detractors start downvoting it and (hopefully) explain why

I fully agree with you @SIGHUP.

@SIGHUP "I came up with precisely this answer" - I'm guessing that's why it was downvoted...

@nocomment Then a comment such as "This is a duplicate" would have been polite and relevant

Got to learn about the Walrus operator, Thank you for the help.

Your desired series is essentially the result of mapping
0 -> 0
1 -> 2
2 -> 6
3 -> 12
4 -> 20
...
9 -> 90

If you plot these on graph paper on using a graphics calculator such as Desmos, you can quickly see that these are the points of the quadratic function f(x) = x * (x+1). Or in other words: to get the i-th number in your sequence, you need to multiply i with (i+1). Therefore, you can use the following comprehension:
[x * (x+1) for x in range(0,10)]


Thank you , for simplifying this, I was quite adamant to make the logic that I came up with into list comprehension,  that I missed this observation. So thank you very much!!
